# How t calculate the number of unique values among multiple columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I calculate the number of unique values among two columns `col1` and  `col2`, grouped by `col0`?

```
 col0   col1   col2
 x      A      B
 x      A      C
 x      C      A
 x      C      D
```

The following command seems to calculate the unique number of combinations of columns:

```
df.groupBy("col0").agg(countDistinct("col1","col2"))
```

The expected output is 4 (A, B, C, D).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`countDistinct` inbuilt function is what you are looking for

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("col0").agg(countDistinct("col1", "col2").as("distinctCounts")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----+--------------+
|col0|distinctCounts|
+----+--------------+
|x   |4             |
+----+--------------+
```

You can go one step further by using `collect_set` inbuilt function to collect distinct strings in each columns and then use a `udf` function get the aggregated distinct strings as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def distinctValues = udf((col1: Seq[String], col2: Seq[String]) => col1 ++ col2 distinct)

df.groupBy("col0").agg(countDistinct("col1", "col2").as("distinctCounts"), distinctValues(collect_set("col1"), collect_set("col2")).as("distinctValues")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
|col0|distinctCounts|distinctValues|
+----+--------------+--------------+
|x   |4             |[C, A, B, D]  |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

One more step further would be to use `sort_array` inbuilt function to sort the distinct strings returned from `udf` function

```
df.groupBy("col0").agg(countDistinct("col1", "col2").as("distinctCounts"), sort_array(distinctValues(collect_set("col1"), collect_set("col2"))).as("distinctValues")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+----+--------------+--------------+
|col0|distinctCounts|distinctValues|
+----+--------------+--------------+
|x   |4             |[A, B, C, D]  |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Could you please have a look at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848977/count-values-in-multiple-columns-that-contain-a-substring-based-on-strings-of-li`