# count values in multiple columns that contain a substring based on strings of lists pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame in `Pyspark` like below. I want to `count` values in two columns based on some `lists` and populate new columns for each `list`

```
df.show()

+---+-------------+-------------_+
| id|       device|  device_model|
+---+-------------+--------------+
|  3|      mac pro|           mac|
|  1|       iphone|       iphone5|
|  1|android phone|       android|
|  1|   windows pc|       windows|
|  1|   spy camera|    spy camera|
|  2|             |        camera|
|  2|       iphone|  apple iphone|
|  3|   spy camera|              |
|  3|         cctv|          cctv|
+---+-------------+--------------+
```

`lists are below`:

```
phone_list = ['iphone', 'android', 'nokia']
pc_list = ['windows', 'mac']
security_list = ['camera', 'cctv']
```

I want to `count` the `device` and `device_model` for each `id` and `pivot` the values in a new data frame.

I want to `count` the values in the both the `device_model` and `device` columns for each `id` that match the `strings` in the list.

For example: in `phone_list` I have a `iphone` string this should count values for both values `iphone` and `iphone5`

The result I want

```
+---+------+----+--------+
| id|phones|  pc|security|
+---+------+----+--------+
|  1|     4|   2|       2|
|  2|     2|null|       1|
|  3|  null|   2|       3|
+---+------+----+--------+
```

I have done like below

```
df.withColumn('cat', 
    F.when(df.device.isin(phone_list), 'phones').otherwise(
    F.when(df.device.isin(pc_list), 'pc').otherwise(
    F.when(df.device.isin(security_list), 'security')))
).groupBy('id').pivot('cat').agg(F.count('cat')).show()
```

Using the above I can only do for `device` column and only if the `string` matches exactly. But unable to figure out how to do for both the columns and when value contains the `string`.

How can I achieve the result I want?

Comment: can you explain the counts? like how you get 4 for phones when id is 1 and pc =2 and security = 2?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan For `Id` column `1` in `device` column I have `iphone` and `android phone` and `device_model` column I have `iphone5` and `android`.

So here the requirement is when in the `phone_list` if the `strings` match any of the `string/substring` then count should be `1` so here I am having `4` values `2` in `device_model` and `2` in `device` that a `string` match. `iphone` matches to `iphone` and `iphone5`. `android` matches to `android phone` and `android` hence the count of `phones for id 1` is `4` same way for the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution . I have used udf function for checking the strings and calculating sum. You can use inbuilt functions if possible. (comments are provided as a means for explanation)

```
#creating dictionary for the lists with names for columns
columnLists = {'phone':phone_list, 'pc':pc_list, 'security':security_list}

#udf function for checking the strings and summing them
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as t
def checkDevices(device, deviceModel, name):
    sum = 0
    for x in columnLists[name]:
        if x in device:
            sum += 1
        if x in deviceModel:
            sum += 1
    return sum

checkDevicesAndSum = F.udf(checkDevices, t.IntegerType())

#populating the sum returned from udf function to respective columns
for x in columnLists:
    df = df.withColumn(x, checkDevicesAndSum(F.col('device'), F.col('device_model'), F.lit(x)))

#finally grouping and sum 
df.groupBy('id').agg(F.sum('phone').alias('phone'), F.sum('pc').alias('pc'), F.sum('security').alias('security')).show()
```

which should give you

```
+---+-----+---+--------+
| id|phone| pc|security|
+---+-----+---+--------+
|  3|    0|  2|       3|
|  1|    4|  2|       2|
|  2|    2|  0|       1|
+---+-----+---+--------+
```

**Aggrgation part can be generalized as the rest of the parts. Improvements and modification is all in your hand**. :)